# Is it valid to say that "find the nullspace of a plane"?

Tags: vector-spaces

The concept of row space&null space and a relation between them and a matrix (also linear transformation) is quite confusing.
Indeed, it is valid to say that, for example, the null space of a matrix (1,1,1,1) is x+y+z+w=0.
Then how about the null space of x+y+z+w=0? I think it is not a proper notation. Could you explain its validity?

Comment: When you say "the matrix $(1,1,1,1)$", do you mean that as a $1\times 4$ (row) matrix?

Comment: @Arthur It is a 1x4 matrix

Comment: A plane could be the nullspace *of* a  system.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog A plane can be a nullspace of a system, but can it also have a nullspace?

Comment: you can consider that it is its own nullspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me define the nullspace of a Matrix. If we're given a Matrix/linear transformation, then the nullspace of the matrix/linear transformation is the set of solutions to the equation $Ax=0$. At first, think about your example. In this case, your matrix $A$= (1 1 1 1) is simply a row matrix. Note that A has one row and four columns. Now, you choose x, which is essentially a column vector ie a matrix that has a single column. Then set $Ax =0$. If you multiply these matrices, you'll get something like $w+x+y+z =0$. Now, what is the solution set/space of this equation? Notice that this solution space is a 3-dimensional subspace of $R^4$.

If you're reading/learning linear algebra for the first time, I can recommend you some cool introductory lectures by Gilbert Strang. I hope this helps.

Comment: Then do you mean that "Nullspace of x+y+z+w=0" is a valid notation, and its basis is (1,1,1,1)?

Comment: Actually I can't understand why it is one-dimensional because it is not 0 if (k,k,k,k) is put in x+y+z+w=0

Comment: My bad. I corrected my mistakes. It's actually a three-dimensional subspace inside $R^4$. In fact, this type of subspace has a particular name. We call them hyperplanes (a generalization of line, and planes). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I understand that a space that satisfies w+x+y+z=0 is certainly a nullspace of A. But can we say that the space is a nullspace of w+x+y+z=0? Is it practically used in mathematics?

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of language.  No one will use the following phrase. "But can we say that space is a nullspace of w+x+y+z=0." Yes, the notion of nullspace is ubiquitous in mathematics.  People use a different kind of "terms" to express the same idea, for example, Nullspace becomes the Kernel of any homomorphism. Particularly, in linear algebra, you'll use nullspace/kernel a lot.  If you ever every study any advanced algebra, you'll find the concept "kernel" pretty much all the time. For example, there is a branch in mathematics called homological algebra. It will not be an exaggeration if I tell you that you'll see the word "kernel" (which is essentially your nullspace :p) on almost every page. Conclusion: You cannot run from nullspace. :p